# T-SQL: Select foreign key from one table and find corresponding rows in another

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables: tblA contains a foreign key which I want to use to pull corresponding rows from tblB. The following queries will not work, but they explain what I want to do:

```
SELECT [MyID]
FROM [tblA]

SELECT [MyColumn]
FROM [tblB]
WHERE [ID] = [tblA].[MyID]
```

This should be a fairly simple query but I am a noob with T-SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`JOIN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT A.MyID, B.MyColumn
FROM tblA A INNER JOIN tblB B
    ON A.MyID= B.ID
```

There are different [types of joins](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), the `INNER JOIN` returns only rows from `tblA` with a matching key in `tblB`.